# Firefox addon to only display specified element

Tags: firefox-extensions

I want to only display one element of a website, and nothing else.

(Some background: In our office we have a big screen that we want to display our app's usage stats - but only one graph of a page of lots of graphs.)  Ideally I would like to specify an XPath that should be displayed for a given URL.

If a Firefox extension isn't going to work, does anyone have any other ideas?

Comment: Create a page that will display only the graph you want?

Comment: Its not our app.  Its a monitoring app that we have no control over.

Comment: Doesn't have to be your app.  Just requires someone to examine the source code of the page that displays the graphs, and then make a page on your own server ( or a free server) to display just the graph you want.  You might even contact the app maker to present your issue.  They might appreciate the support, and make the page for you.

Comment: I'll ask them anyway as a feature request to view each graph individually.  I wanted to know if there isn't a way of doing this without server changing its code, just client side.

Comment: You can try RIP (Remove it Permanently) https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/remove-it-permanently/ as it is highly configurable.